# Sort post by attributes 'order'

Tags: posts, order, customization

How to sort the displayed posts by attribute "order"?

In functions.php I added the "Attributes" for posts

```
function wpzen_add_attributes_to_post() {
    add_post_type_support('post', 'page-attributes');
}
add_action('init', 'wpzen_add_attributes_to_post');
function wpzen_change_post_order($query) {
    if($query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'menu_order');
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpzen_change_post_order');
```

The code displays an overview of posts looks like this:

```
<?php
        $show_posts = '12';
        $cat_name = 'Products';
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $my_query = new WP_query('category_name=' . $cat_name . '&showposts=' . $show_posts . '&paged=' . $paged );

        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->in_the_loop = true;

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </a>
    <?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

How to sort posts according to the attribute "order" (ascending or descending).

Comment: Sorting posts by `menu_order` is a bad idea. Posts, unlike pages, are not hierarchical and their `menu_order` is normally 0 ( unless you change it manually or by a plugin ). Usually, you sort posts by something unique, like `date` ( default ) or `ID`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm afraid it won't work this way. Let me explain why...

In your `wpzen_change_post_order` function you check if `$query->is_main_query()`. To be precise, this checks, if given query is main query for current page - the query generated by WP to display default posts for current page.

So if you create your own `WP_Query` object, then this condition will be false and your function wont set `orderby` parameter.

**How to change that?**

There are to ways to fix that. First: remove the if statement from `wpzen_change_post_order`. But then you should be careful and add some other checks in there, so you'll be sure, that you modify only queries that you really want to. (Especially you should check, `if ( ! is_admin() )`)

Second way, much easier, I guess... Add `orderby` parameter directly in your `WP_Query`. So the code that displays posts would look like this:

```
<?php
        $show_posts = '12';
        $cat_name = 'Products';
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        $my_query = new WP_Query( array(  // <- It's better to use array
           'category_name' => $cat_name,
           'posts_per_page' => $show_posts,  // <- showposts is deprecated for long time, so use posts_per_page instead
           'paged' => $paged,
           'orderby' => 'menu_order'
        ) );

        global $wp_query;  // <- I'm not sure what do you want to accomplish with these 2 lines
        $wp_query->in_the_loop = true;

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </a>
    <?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```